# Wordpress location search by zip code

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, location, zipcode

I need to do the following in a client Wordpress based site.

1- The user enters an us zip code
2- List the stores near that zip code (no more than 50 miles away)

I only have the zip codes of each store, no coordinates.

Is it possible to do this using google maps or a similar service? I need to do this only with the zip codes, the other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check this plugin.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/store-locator/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Wordpress plugin [www.geomywp.com](http://geomywp.com)